# C#: Searching through arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, search

I have a dvd app that stores dvds and blu-rays, I want to search the arrays by director. Below is the code for the inventory class  I have seen many different ways to do this.  There seems to be some debate as the best/most efficient way to accomplish this, any suggestions?

Blockquote

```
    namespace MovieInventoryApplication
{
class Inventory
{
    public Bluray[] BlurayMovies;
    public DVD[] DVDMovies;

    private int blurayCount;
    private int dvdCount;

    public Inventory()
    {
        BlurayMovies = new Bluray[5];
        DVDMovies = new DVD[5];

        blurayCount = 0;
        dvdCount = 0;
    }

    public void AddBluray()
    {
        String strTitle;
        int intReleaseYear;
        int intRunningTimeMinutes;
        String strDirector;
        int intPrice;
        int intRegionCode;

        try
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a title: ");
            strTitle = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter a release year: ");
            intReleaseYear = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter the running time in minutes: ");
            intRunningTimeMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter the directors name: ");
            strDirector = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter a rental price: ");
            intPrice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            BlurayMovies[blurayCount] = new Bluray(strTitle, intReleaseYear, intRunningTimeMinutes, strDirector, intPrice);
            blurayCount++;

            Console.Write("Enter the DVD region code: ");
            intRegionCode = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            DVDMovies[dvdCount] = new DVD(strTitle, intReleaseYear, intRunningTimeMinutes, strDirector, intPrice, intRegionCode);
            dvdCount++;
        }
        catch (FormatException FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(FormatException.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number in this field.");
        }
    }

    public void AddDVD()
    {
        String strTitle;
        int intReleaseYear;
        int intRunningTimeMinutes;
        String strDirector;
        int intPrice;
        int intRegionCode;

        try
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a title: ");
            strTitle = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter a release year: ");
            intReleaseYear = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter the running time in minutes: ");
            intRunningTimeMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter the directors name: ");
            strDirector = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter a rental price: ");
            intPrice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter the region code: ");
            intRegionCode = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            DVDMovies[dvdCount] = new DVD(strTitle, intReleaseYear, intRunningTimeMinutes, strDirector, intPrice, intRegionCode);
            dvdCount++;
        }

        catch (FormatException FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(FormatException.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number in this field.");
        }
    }

    public void ListAllBluray()
    {
        int position = 0;

        while (BlurayMovies[position] != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(position + " " + BlurayMovies[position].strTitle);

            position++;
        }
    }

    public void ListAllDVD()
    {
        int position = 0;

        while (DVDMovies[position] != null)
        {
            //position + 1 + " " + 
            Console.WriteLine(position + " " + DVDMovies[position].strTitle);

            position++;
        }
    }

    public void BlurayInfo(int position)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", DVDMovies[position].strTitle);
        Console.WriteLine("Release Year: {0}", DVDMovies[position].intReleaseYear);
        Console.WriteLine("Running Time (Minutes): {0}", DVDMovies[position].intRunningTimeMinutes);
        Console.WriteLine("Director: {0}", DVDMovies[position].strDirector);
        Console.WriteLine("Price: {0}", DVDMovies[position].intPrice);
    }

    public void DVDInfo(int position)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", DVDMovies[position].strTitle);
        Console.WriteLine("Release Year: {0}", DVDMovies[position].intReleaseYear);
        Console.WriteLine("Running Time (Minutes): {0}", DVDMovies[position].intRunningTimeMinutes);
        Console.WriteLine("Director: {0}", DVDMovies[position].strDirector);
        Console.WriteLine("Price: {0}", DVDMovies[position].intPrice);
        Console.WriteLine("Region Code: {0}", DVDMovies[position].intRegionCode);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What's the debate?  What have you tried?

Comment: Like results = Array.FindAll(arr, s => s.Equals(target) or bool has = arr.Contains(var).  I have seen many different ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a flaw in the design.

The DVD and BluRay classes really should be either:

1. A single class with a `Type` property, probably an enum that would contain DVD and BluRay. This way, in several years once you get a new media, you can just add a value to the Enum and your application will be up to date.
2. Two different classes that implement a custom interface that you could call, say, `IMedia`.

Also, I highly suggest you take advantage of the `List` object in C# instead of arrays. It's very fast and you can add/remove items easily without having to resize your array.

Here's a lesson on Linq: http://www.functionx.com/csharp/linq/Lesson09.htm

Here's how I would create the Media class:

```
public class Media
{
    public enum MediaType
    {
        DVD,
        Bluray
    }

    public MediaType TypeOfMedia { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Media(string Title, string Director, MediaType TypeOfMedia)
    {
        this.TypeOfMedia = TypeOfMedia;
        this.Director = Director;
        this.Title = Title;
    }
}
```

And here's an example how to use it:

```
        List<Media> data = new List<Media>();

        results.Add(new Media("Movie 1", "John D", Media.MediaType.DVD));
        results.Add(new Media("Movie 2", "John D", Media.MediaType.DVD));
        results.Add(new Media("Movie 3", "SomeOtherDirector", Media.MediaType.Bluray));
        results.Add(new Media("Movie 4", "John D", Media.MediaType.Bluray));

        IEnumerable<Media> listDirectors = from media in data
                                           where media.Director == "John D"
                                           select media;

        foreach (Media media in listDirectors)
            Console.WriteLine(media.Title);
```

Another example, your "List DVD" and "List Bluray" functions could really be a single function:

```
    private void ListMediaByType(List<Media> data, Media.MediaType type)
    {
        foreach (Media media in data.Where(media => media.TypeOfMedia == type))
            Console.WriteLine(media.Title);
    }
```

As you see, these techniques simplifies querying by a LOT. :)

Comment: All of the above is also possible using Arrays by the way! In the ListMediaByType, feel free to change List<Media> into Media[].

Answer (score 0):

The most easies (imho) is using Linq:

```
string director = "Alfred Hitchcock";
IEnumerable<DVD> dvds = DVDMovies.Where(dvd => dvd.Director == director);
IEnumerable<DVD> blueRays = BlurayMovies.Where(br => br.Director == director);
List<DVD> allMatches = new List<DVD>();
allMatches.AddRange(dvds.Concat(blueRays));
```

Comment: Tim, unfortunately he is using 2 separate classes (DVD and Bluray) - I don't think you can generate an IEnum<DVD> from the Bluray array.

Comment: I realize a list makes more sense, but I'm gonna stick with an array

Comment: @Joe: the code is  a little bit confusing but he's just using one class `DVD`. You have to look in the `AddXYZ` methods.

Comment: @JonathanOberhaus: You haven't mentioned that the result collection should also be an array. But it's as simple as: `dvds.Concat(blueRays).ToArray()`.

Comment: Oh, indeed. Still, this is unmaintanable code, so I'll suggest enhancing the DVD class to encompass any sort of media.